# R Shiny cant publish to shinyapps but runs locally

Tags: r, shiny

I have a deployed shinyapp that I want to update but cant since the publish button returns an error

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 863946472 failed: Error building image: Error building installr (0.22.0). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
Execution halted
```

Both R and shiny is recently updated and Im on renv. Used to be able to update the app but now I cant. I dont know what to do since if theres something wrong in the code the app shouldnt be running locally.
Tried publishing to a totally new app but same results

I appreciate any leads on this.

Comment: Faced a similar problem before, worked after completely moving away from renv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While uploading, can you try by not uploading the `renv` related files?

Comment: Rhe problem was with using installR in the renv. I used installR to update R but never called the package in my app. Uninstalled installR in renv and globally, my app worked again.